# How do I open a port on IIS and access it outside the server

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a Windows VM running Windows Server 2012 on Google Cloud and have installed 2 web application on IIS on the server. Let's take the example IP as 1.2.3.4 One application is hosted on port 80 and bound at abc.com while the other application is hosted at port 81.

I am able to access the website at abc.com however, when trying to access as 1.2.3.4:80 or 1.2.3.4:81, the website is not accessible. Please advise how to open the ports.

Comment: Ports are opened on firewalls, not IIS. In case of Google Cloud, you have at least two firewalls to configure, Windows Firewall on the server itself, and the cloud firewall (check Google documentation).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Can you help me with any link to configure firewall on server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a port issue. You should add correct binding to your sites. If you want to access site by server ip, add binding like this:
[image]

Comment: I have done the same, but it looks like the server IIS is not accessible using the IP address.